# Meteor : count value

Tags: meteor

again anyone please help me. I still cannot solve this problem.I want to count categories but still not working. This my code.

```
    //js 
Template.count.helpers({
      profil: function() {
        Meteor.call("profil", function(err, res){
         if(!err) Session.set("profil", res);
        });
        return Session.get("profil");
      }
    });

//server
Meteor.methods({
  profil: function () {
        return Profil.find({status: 'available',
  categories: 'PTR' }).count();
    }
});

//html
{{profil}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `{{profil}}` inside the template, e.g. like so: `<template name="count"> {{profil}} </template>`?

Also, that will not run reactively.  You must place `Profil.find({status: 'available',  categories: 'PTR' }).count();` directly in the helper method for it to register a dependency (i.e. automatically update when the Profil collection is updated.)

This should work and be reactive:

```
// js 
Template.count.helpers({
  profil: function() {
    return Profil.find({status: 'available',  categories: 'PTR' }).count();
  }
});


 // html
 <template name="count"> {{profil}} </template>
```

Comment: Thank, this code are working. one more question how to display more categories like PTR and COM. I do like this code Profil.find({status: 'available',
  categories: { $in: ['PTR', 'COM'] }
}).count(); . This code just read one time only.

Comment: Could you please clarify this new question?  Also, could you please mark this as answered if it did answer your question?

Comment: Use `Profil.find({status: 'available', categories: { $in: ['PTR', 'COM'] } })` in the js and `<template name="count"> {{#each profil}} {{PTR}} {{COM}} {{/each}}</template>` in the html.

This is elementary meteor though so you really should go through and understand their [excellent tutorials](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/creating-an-app) first!

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple:reactive-method for these type of methods call.

Before (doesn't work)

```
Template.foo.helpers({
   methodResult: function () {
       Meteor.call("myMethod", "a", "b", function (err, result) {
           return result; // this doesn't work!!!
       });
   } 
});
```

After (works!)

```
Template.foo.helpers({
    methodResult: function () {
        // Super fun!
        return ReactiveMethod.call("myMethod", "a", "b");

        // Can also use 'apply' style
        // return ReactiveMethod.apply("myMethod", ["a", "b"]);
    }
});
```

For more info you can check this [link](https://atmospherejs.com/simple/reactive-method)